# DTF XMLSchemaExtension issue in WiX

Tags: wix, custom-action, dtf

I am creating a custom WiX extension using the Deployment Tools Foundation (DTF) framework. I have created the necessary wixlib and extension classes.
The problem is when I refer this extension through my .wxs file, I am getting the below error message:

> "Error    7   The Product element contains an unexpected child element
>   'ca:CAAppPool'. some of the warning from xsd validation 
>   Message   1   Could not find schema information for the element
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2005/XmlSchemaExtension:parent'.

Below is the some extract from my XSD file:

`xmlns:xse="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2005/XmlSchemaExtension"` in our schema definition file to refer my component tag to be child of `Product`/`Fragment` as below:

```
<xs:appinfo>
   <xse:parent namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" ref="Product" />
   <xse:parent namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" ref="Fragment" />
</xs:appinfo>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to strip out the xs:appinfo elements before compiling the contents in your extension. You'll see the standard WiX extensions do this by using the custom FlattenXml MSBuild tasks to trim down the XSD to only what is necessary in the extension.